# How can I make ultrasonic sensors resistent to splashes and dirt?

Tags: sensors

I wasn't sure where to ask this question, but since it's actually an Arduino project, I'll try it here.

I want to upgrade my old car with ultrasonic parking sensors: I've already bought HC-SR04s as sensors and started to play on my breadboard.

But what I'm still unsure about: if I place them in my car's rear bumber, how can I make them resistent to rain or dirt or something like that?
As pictured on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parking_sensors), the sensor is covered with a small piece. But what could I use to cover the holes in the bumper, without interfering with the ultrasonic measuring?

Comment: I'd try thin rubber (e.g. from a latex glove). Or some other kind of thin plastic. Just try out some of the plastics from food containers you'd normally throw out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to cover that sensor in a way that will still allow it to work. There are waterproof ultrasonic sensors out there, here's one on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BJTRGQW), for example.

The other thing you might want to look at is IR instead of ultrasonic. That's easier to weatherproof since the IR emitter/receiver are already covered. You'll probably have less range with IR, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe at a minimum for testing you could point the sensor downwards and then use a reflector to discourage water and dust. Something like: http://letsmakerobots.com/content/cyperbolic-reflector-review